# Is it possible to define $b$ in terms of $c$, $ d$, and $mk$ given that $a-b=m k=c-d$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, regular-expressions

Given the following:
$$a-b=mk, \qquad c-d=mk$$
For some integers $a,b,c,d,m,k$ I need to express $b$ in terms of $c,d,$ and $mk$ in order for my proof to work, but no matter how I fiddle around with this I can’t do it.  Is it possible?

Comment: Well... no.  If $mk = 20$ and $c= 30$ and $d=10$ there any one expression of $f(c,d) = f(30,10)$ will always have one specific value.  But $b$ need not be one specific value.  $b$ could be $16$ (if $a= 36$) or $b$ could be $92$ (if $a =112$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you could and you had $b = f(c,d)$.

Let $c_0; d_0$ be a pair of numbers so that $c_0-d_0 = mk$.  That would mean that if $a - b = mk$ that $b$ *must* be equal to $f(c_0, d_0)$.  But notice $(a+1) - (b+1) = mk$ as well.  So that means that $b+1 = f(c_0, d_0)$ as well.  But $f(c_0, d_0)$ can't be equal to two different things.

If you think about it, this question makes no sense.  There are an infinite number of pairs of $(a= mk + b, b)$ so that $a-b = mk$ and there are an infinite number of pairs of $(c,d)$ where $c-d = mk$.  Which $b$ you pick to get $a-b = mk$ and which pair of $(c,d)$ you pick to get $c-d = mk$ are completely independent.  There's no way picking a specific $(c,d)$ can determine one precise $b$ because... you can always just pick another $b$ instead.